# Append node to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, logging, append

I need to append a node to a possibly huge XML file used as log. The average time between one insertion and the following is of 200ms. At the moment I use the following method:

```
private void LogMessage(Message m)
{
    lock (loglock)
    {
        // load XML
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(MyLogFilename);
        var root = doc.ChildNodes[0];

        // append node
        var node = GetXmlNode(doc, m);
        root.AppendChild(node);

        // save new XML
        doc.Save(MyLogFilename);
    }
}
```

I need to lock because the method can be called from different threads. It works, but I would like to avoid to load the entire file every time. Is there a better way or any workaround in order to get the same outcome?

Comment: `I would like to avoid to load the entire file every time` so what was the problem when you saved the xml to a field or property instead?

Comment: @Jonesopolis The problem was (and is) to store all the XmlDocument in memory.

Comment: @Nick perhaps you could keep part of the XDoc in memory. Then merge the amendments into the physical doc every 30 seconds?